# Multiple associations to the same model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, heroku

Let's say I have a model Dogs and each dog has exactly 2 Cat "enemies", `enemy1` and `enemy2`, how do I write the migration file such that I can call `dog.enemy1` to retrieve the first enemy and `dog.enemy2` to retrieve the second enemy?
I tried this:

```
create_table :dog do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :dog, :name

    add_foreign_key :dogs, :cats, column: :enemy1_id
    add_foreign_key :dogs, :cats, column: :enemy2_id
end
```

I also tried it with the `t.references` method but could not get it to work. Been working on this problem for hours. and it works fine in development but not on Heroku Postgres.
The error i get is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:column     "enemy1_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Migration:

```
create_table :dog do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.integer :enemy1_id
  t.integer :enemy2_id
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Dog Model:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :enemy1, class: 'Cat', foreign_key: :enemy1_id
  has_one :enemy2, class: 'Cat', foreign_key: :enemy2_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a 'has_two' association in rails. So you should settle with has_many association.

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cats, limit: 2

  scope :enemy1, Proc.new { |object| object.cats.first }
  scope :enemy2, Proc.new { |object| object.cats.last }
end
```

in class cat

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

Now the migration for create cats should have

```
t.references :dog
```

You need not have foreign fields in your dog model. This should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails Way should not be to do this in a migration. Migrations, in my opinion, is a tool to define the structure your data would live in.

The Rails Way would suggest you have a `has_many` association on the Cat class for Dogs

```
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  # ... other code ...
  has_many :enemies, class_name: Cat
  # ... other code ...
end
```

You'd also have to define the belongs to association in Cat

```
class Cat < ApplicationRecord
  # ... other code ...
  belongs_to :dog
  # ... other code ...
end
```

Note that the `cats` table should be defined to have a reference to the `dogs` table. So your migration for the cats table should read something like

```
class CreateCats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.x]
  create_table :cats do |t|
    # ... other code ...
    t.references :dog
    # ... other code ...
  end
end
```

With these setup, you should then define `enemy_one` and `enemy_two` in your Dog class

```
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  # ... other code ...
  def enemy_one
    enemies.first
  end

  def enemy_two
    enemies.second
  end
  # ... other code ...
end
```

To make things even stricter, you may decide to add a validation (on create) which checks that only two Cats are ever created as enemies per Dog. Moreso, you could hide the creating button (or general access) when a Dog has reached its limit for enemies. This, I leave to your discretion.

p.s: All these constrictions could also be done in the database layer. But the application layer is here to abstract all that out.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved it independently, 2 seconds after the first answer came in..
Finally.

```
class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :dogs do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.references :enemy1, index: true
        t.references :enemy2, index: true

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :dogs, :name

    add_foreign_key :dogs, :cats, column: :enemy1_id
    add_foreign_key :dogs, :cats, column: :enemy2_id
end
```